# jquery plugin for horizontal scrolling like touch swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling, iscroll

I'm trying to find a jquery plugin which will make mousewheel scrolling (horizontal) behave like touch swipe (when scrolled to end or start, it makes a nice smooth effect like touch phone).
The closest I could find is iscroll:
http://jonathanstark.com/labs/iscroll/examples/horizontal-scroll/

but the mousewheel behave same like default.

I found a wordpress theme which using a gallery jquery script which include the same behavioral I want:
http://contrast.freevision.me/
but I want to have the jquery plugin independent without the need to use this heavy gallery script.

Anyone know any good jquery plugin for it?

Thanks!